# UIButton to append array of UIViews to UIStackView

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview, uistackview

I have this code, but it is only appending the first uiview. I also want the label in the uiview to display the string from arrayTwo. It's only printing the count right now.

I have the stackView in storyboard set to fill equally. And only top, trailing and leading constraints.

If I don't care about animation, can I append to a container UIView and the same code should just work? Obviously swapping out the stackView for a uiview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var arrayButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    
    var arrayView = MyView()   /// lives inside a nib only has one uilabel
    var arrayOfView: [MyView] = [] 
    var arrayTwo = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    var arrayIndex = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stackView.spacing = 4
    }

    func appendViews() {
        
        for i in 0...arrayTwo.count - 1 {
            arrayOfView.append(arrayView)
            //arrayOfView[I].myLabel.text = arrayTwo[i]
            arrayOfView[i].myLabel.text = arrayTwo.first
            
            stackView.addSubview(arrayOfView[i])
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(arrayOfView[i])
       }
 
    }
    
    @IBAction func arrayButton Action(_ sender: Any) {
        appendViews()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code repeatedly adds the same object to the array:

```swift
arrayOfView.append(arrayView)
```

I assume that `MyView` is a class inherited from `UIView`, so in Swift in has reference type semantics ([read more about value and reference types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)). When this line gets executed, no new instance of `MyView` gets created, instead the reference to the same existing object gets added to the array. Later, when you add subviews to the stack view, it just tries adding the same view over and over again.

What you need instead is to create a new instance of `MyView` for every iteration. That said, you'll no longer need the `arrayView` property.

There are also a few other issues that can be addressed:

1. The raw for-loop can be replaced with a much safer `for-in` statement to avoid operating directly with array indices.
2. You almost never call the `addSubview` for `UIStackView` because it will not automatically arrange the views added that way. Calling just `addArrangedSubview` is what you always want.
3. The `arrayIndex` property seems to be unused and can be deleted.
4. `arrayTwo` is not a good name because it doesn't tell anything about the contents and the semantics, try making it more descriptive like `labelTexts`.

After all you get something like this:

```swift
for text in labelTexts {
    let myView = MyView()
    arrayOfView.append(myView)
    myView.myLabel.text = text
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(myView)
}
```